# VirtualBox does not want to open a session for the virtual machine

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have a problem with the vagrant and virtualbox (virtualbox-qt 4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu2). When I was doing the command: `vagrant up`, I get this message:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty32' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8080 => 6389 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.
```

When I run the virtual machine at startup, I get this error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine booklock_server_default_1427275442366_68003.

VT-x is not available. (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

Result code (RC): NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox is trying to use hardware virtualization. Check if your hardware supports vt-x, then make sure it is enabled in BIOS. If you do not have hardware virtualization or can't enable it on your machine, you will unfortunately not be able to run 64-bit guest operation system in VirtualBox, see: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used this command: egrep -c '(vmx | svm) '/proc/cpuinfo and I got 0. This means that my machine does not support virtualization, what then?

Comment: Without hardware virtualization you can only run a VM  using a 32-bit guest operation system with one CPU, see https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11659

Comment: In Virtualbox I have set Ubuntu 32-bit